# Example of using github API from javascript

Tags: javascript, github-api

I've been searching on the web for some time and couldn't find an example of how to use the [GitHub API](http://developer.github.com/v3/) from plain client-side javascript (no node-js, jquery etc). I wanted something like authenticate then push a blob, put as simply as possible so I can understand it. Shouldn't be too complicated, I bet you can do that in a dozen lines of code but I don't know a lot about ajax, json and jsonp.

Can you provide an example to get me started?

Thanks!

**edit:** found this: http://blog.vjeux.com/category/javascript, but I'm still confused as to what are exactly the steps of the process.

Comment: Add an answer with links. It would be greatly appreciated. I do have some understanding of those as concepts but never implemented anything using those techniques myself.

Comment: The link in edit is not appropriate for your question.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you're looking to use with vanilla JavaScript (i.e. no framework), you need to play around with the `XMLHttpRequest` object. The `XMLHttpRequest` provides the core for AJAX implementations.

Despite the `XMLHttp` prefix, you're not limited to XML or HTTP. You can retrieve any data type (such as JSON) and use other protocols such as FTP.

Say we'd like to `GET` your user information from GitHub. From a browser, we can easily make the request by visiting https://api.github.com/users/funchal.
Sending an HTTP request in JavaScript is just as simple with `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
// Create a new request object
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Initialize a request
request.open('get', 'https://api.github.com/users/funchal')
// Send it
request.send()
```

If you give this a go from a JavaScript console, you might feel a bit disappointed: nothing will happen immediately. You'll have to wait for the server to respond to your request. From the time you create the instantiate the request object till when the server responds, the object will undergo a series of state changes denoted by the value of the `readyState` property:

- 0 `UNSENT`: `open()` uncalled
- 1 `OPENED`: `send()` uncalled
- 2 `HEADERS_RECIEVED`: headers and status are available after a `send()`
- 3 `LOADING`: the `responseText` is still downloading
- 4 `DONE`: Wahoo!

Once all is finished, you can check the `response` attribute for the data:

```
request.readyState // => 4 (We've waited enough)
request.response // => "{whatever}"
```

When using `XMLHttpRequest#open()`, you have a few options to consider. Here's the method signature:

```
void open(
   DOMString method,
   DOMString url,
   optional boolean async,
   optional DOMString user,
   optional DOMString password
);
```

The third parameter, which defaults to true, dictates whether the response should be made asynchronously. If you set this to `false`, you'll have to wait until the response is complete for `#send()` to return, and you'll pay the price of blocking your whole program. As such, we code in an *asynchronous* fashion so that our program remains responsive even while we wait. This asynchronicity is achieved by using and event listeners (a.k.a. event handlers) and callback functions.

Say we want to simply dump the response to the console once it arrives. We first need to create a callback function that we'd like to execute `onload`:

```
function dumpResponse() {
  // `this` will refer to the `XMLHTTPRequest` object that executes this function
  console.log(this.responseText);
}
```

Then we set this callback as the listener/handler for the `onload` event defined by the `XMLHttpRequest` interface:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
// Set the event handler
request.onload = dumpResponse;
// Initialize the request
request.open('get', 'https://api.github.com/users/funchal', true)
// Fire away!
request.send()
```

Now since you'll be receiving the data as a string, you'll need to parse the string with `JSON.parse()` to do anything meaningful. Say I want to debug the number of public repositories you have along with your name. I can use this function to parse the string into JSON, and then I can pull the attributes I want:

```
function printRepoCount() {
  var responseObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  console.log(responseObj.name + " has " + responseObj.public_repos + " public repositories!");
}
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onload = printRepoCount;
request.open('get', 'https://api.github.com/users/funchal', true)
request.send()
// => Giovanni Funchal has 8 public repositories!
```

See [the W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/) and the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FXMLHttpRequest%2FUsing_XMLHttpRequest) for more info on `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: hi @faraz. is it possible to authenticate as myself in javascript on the client side when sending XHRs to the github api v3 to avoid the smaller api rate limit? I see examples of self-authenticating when making api calls via cURL, but I haven't seen an example for doing it on the client. Would this be a bad practice due to having to expose some private key of mine? Thanks for any help and for breaking down the XHR process above!

Comment: An example of curl api calls that I referenced above is: `curl -u username https://api.github.com/user`.

Comment: In german, we would say: this doc is made for the housewife and the minister (für Hausfrauen und Minister). Thanks!.