# Get public user data from github using Promises and xmlhttpRequests?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get user data from github using an url, I am new to dealing with APIs. I tried to follow [github-api](http://github-tools.github.io/github/docs/3.0.0/index.html), but the code there makes little sense to me. I understand the concept of promises, so I tried to couple up this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341135/example-of-using-github-api-from-javascript) with promises and tried to implement it as below. I am working with node.

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

function pr() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request.open('get', 'https://api.github.com/users/$username')
    request.send();
    resolve(request.response);
  });
}

var gitpr = pr();
gitpr.then(function() {
  console.log(request.response);
})
```

My `request.response` `[[PromiseValue]]` is undefined on running the code in node.

Whereas the result in console is correct if I follow this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341135/example-of-using-github-api-from-javascript)(same as above).

Comment: you didn't define an "onload" event handler function for your XMLHttpRequest...you're not waiting for the request to complete before you resolve the Promise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing anything to wait for the request to return!

XMLHttpRequest will notify you when the request is complete with `onreadystatechange`

Below is a pr() function that accomplishes your objectives, assuming "$username" is something meaningful.

Note: I have put the request object into the function for better encapsulation, and am communicating the value of the response to the caller via the resolve:

```
function pr() {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState == 4) {
        resolve(request.responseText);
      }
    }
    request.open('get', 'https://api.github.com/users/$username', true)
    request.send();
  });
}
```

`resolve` then sends the `responseText` member of the response to the function that is awaiting the Promise in the value of it's first function:

```
pr().then(function(val) {
  console.log(val)
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err)
})
```

In the pr() function we are not calling reject() so that err function can't be called, but it would be a good idea to, for example, check for an error status code and call `reject` on that.

Comment: Why do I need **Promise** if the call is asynchronous (via xmlhttprequest) and therefore is like a Promise in itself. Is Promise here double, so too much?