# How can I submit an issue on GitHub from React Native application?

Tags: javascript, react-native, github, expo

I am looking to integrate a `textbox` in my `react native` application where someone can enter a bug description and on submit have it show up on our `Github` `issues` tab.

Does anyone know how I could go about doing this?

Comment: Check out the Github API. It's not something I'm familiar with but you will find what you're looking for here https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue

Comment: Once you understand the API, you will then need to make your application call the API: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341135/example-of-using-github-api-from-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution here from Github's API: [Github Developer - Create an Issue](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/issues#create-an-issue)